# how to access Ubuntu one on Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-one

how do i access the Ubuntu one folder while using Ubuntu 14?  I am doing a school project and need to solve this.

I have tried searching for it, and can't find it anywhere in the Operating System.  I have also tried updating my software to current, but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that The Ubuntu One Files Services have been closed. This is the original post that announce plans to shut down the Ubuntu One file services.   http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was shut down a bit ago now. I think there was a certian amout of time you could get your files off, but that has now passed. Did you do a backup of your drive on a regular basis? Or could you look at retrieving your files from a backup of your system, that included your old Ubuntu One file?

Going forward this link may be of use to you. I personally use copy as dropbox only give you 2gb free(rest are 15) and google drive seems to want you to convert all files to google docs format. That is a personal choice though:

[On-line drive options](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/three-alternatives-ubuntu-one)